# C++ Allegro 5 error

Tags: c++, allegro, allegro5

I am trying to learn some allegro 5 principles with youtube tutorials and here is my first problem .

```
#include<allegro5/allegro.h> 
#include<allegro5/allegro_native_dialog.h> 
#include<allegro5/allegro_primitives.h>
#include<Windows.h>

#define ScreenWidth 800 
#define ScreenHeight 600

int main()
{
    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display; 

    if(!al_init())
    {
        al_show_native_message_box(NULL, NULL,  "Error" ,  "Could not initialize Allegro 5" , NULL, ALLEGRO_MESSAGEBOX_ERROR); 
        return -1;
    }
    display = al_create_display(ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight); 

    if(!display)
    {
        al_show_native_message_box(NULL, NULL,  "Error" ,  "Could not create Allegro 5 display" , NULL, ALLEGRO_MESSAGEBOX_ERROR);
        return -1;
    }

    al_set_new_display_flags(ALLEGRO_NOFRAME);
    al_set_window_position(display, 200, 100);
    al_set_window_title(display,  "CodingMadeEasy" );


    system("pause");
    al_draw_triangle(10, 10, 20, 10, 25, 50, al_map_rgb(255, 0, 0), 1.0);
    system("pause");


    al_flip_display();
    al_rest(5.0);
    al_destroy_display(display);

    return 0;
}
```

There are no sytnax errors but when the program works it gets stuck on the `al_draw_triangle(10, 10, 20, 10, 25, 50, al_map_rgb(255, 0, 0), 1.0);` function . Here are the snapshots of the console and the error message box .
[image]
[image]

Please help me to fix this problem .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose that you've got to call `al_init_primities_addon()`. [Here](https://www.allegro.cc/forums/thread/610141) you find more informaton about this error.

Comment: @AbrahamyanSamvel, this is the correct answer, so you should click the checkbox to mark it as accepted.